# Formatting related datetime field

Tags: python, odoo, openerp-6

I have a related datetime field

```
'expected_date'     : fields.related('picking_id','date',type='datetime', relation='stock.picking', store=True, string="Date"),
```

Then I want to show that field in some report, but I want to change the format of the field using this code

```
'picking_date' : datetime.strftime(datetime.strptime(str(expected_date), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),'%d-%m-%Y'),
```

Then I got this error

> time data 'None' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'

Where did I go wrong? I'm using openerp6.

Comment: CAn you show us the value of `expected_date`?

Comment: 02/10/2015 07:00:00, but when I change the format to '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S' it still showing me same error

Comment: what is the type of `expected_date`? you can check it using `type(expected_date)`. If it is a `datetime` based object, then you do not need to convert it to `str` and then use `strptime` .

Comment: it's returning to be a None type?

Comment: Bah, then it is not a valid datetime value...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`expected_date` is probably `None` so `str(expected_date)` returns the string value `"None"`, hence the does not match error.

You probably want

```
'picking_date' : (expected_date is not None
    and datetime.strftime(datetime.strptime(str(expected_date), '%Y-s%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),'%d-%m-%Y')
    or 'None'),
```

Comment: It's keep showing me same error, but by the way I'm using query to get the field so it became item[2]. It's affecting the result of that expected_date field?

Comment: It's not afecting the field men! Thank you for your answer